# How should I encode an audio stream for Google Voice recognition in golang?

Tags: go, voice-recognition, discord, opus

I'm building a discord bot that uses an Opus stream. I've tried various things such as sending the Opus packets up directly, decoding the OPUS stream to a PCM and encoding it into a byte array, and converting the PCM to a byte array directly. In all cases I get:

Could not recognize: code:11 message:"Audio data is being streamed too slow. Please stream audio data approximately at real time."

I've tried 8kHz-48kHz frequencies at 20 ms frames. I've also tried to encode the converted PCM with the max bitrate. I have run the sample code successfully, so there is no connection issue on my end. Where should I look for a solution?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "flag"

    speech "cloud.google.com/go/speech/apiv1"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    speechpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/speech/v1"

    "github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo"
    "layeh.com/gopus"
)

// OnError gets called by dgvoice when an error is encountered.
// By default logs to STDERR
var OnError = func(str string, err error) {
    prefix := "dgVoice: " + str

    if err != nil {
        os.Stderr.WriteString(prefix + ": " + err.Error())
    } else {
        os.Stderr.WriteString(prefix)
    }
}

var stream speechpb.Speech_StreamingRecognizeClient

func main() {
    var (
        Token     = flag.String("t", "", "Discord bot token.")
//      Email     = flag.String("e", "", "Discord account email.")
//      Password  = flag.String("p", "", "Discord account password.")
        GuildID   = flag.String("g", "", "Guild ID")
        ChannelID = flag.String("c", "", "Channel ID")
    )
    flag.Parse()


    fmt.Println("Connecting to Discord...")
    // Connect to Discord
    discord, err := discordgo.New(*Token)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Opening Socket...")
    // Open Websocket
    err = discord.Open()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Joining Channel...")
    // Connect to voice channel.
    // NOTE: Setting mute to false, deaf to true.
    dgv, err := discord.ChannelVoiceJoin(*GuildID, *ChannelID, false, false)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Connecting to Google Speech Recognition API...")
    ctx := context.Background()

    // [START speech_streaming_mic_recognize]
    client, err := speech.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    stream, err = client.StreamingRecognize(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Send the initial configuration message.
    if err := stream.Send(&speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest{
        StreamingRequest: &speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest_StreamingConfig{
            StreamingConfig: &speechpb.StreamingRecognitionConfig{
                Config: &speechpb.RecognitionConfig{
                    Encoding:        speechpb.RecognitionConfig_LINEAR16,
                    SampleRateHertz: 16000,
                    LanguageCode:    "en-US",
                },
                //InterimResults: true,
                SingleUtterance: true,
            },

        },
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    recv := make(chan *discordgo.Packet, 2)
    go Receive(dgv, recv)

    send := make(chan []int16, 2)
    go Send(dgv, send)

    // dgv.Speaking(true)
 //     defer dgv.Speaking(false)

    go func() {
        for {

            p, ok := <-recv
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("Not OK")
                return
            }

            send <- p.PCM
        }

    } ()

    for {
        resp, err := stream.Recv()
        //fmt.Printf("%+v\n",resp)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Cannot stream results: %v", err)
        }
        if err := resp.Error; err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Could not recognize: %v", err)
        }
        for _, result := range resp.Results {
            fmt.Printf("Result: %+v\n", result)
        }
    }

    // Close connections
    dgv.Close()
    discord.Close()

    return
}

func Receive(v *discordgo.VoiceConnection, c chan *discordgo.Packet) {
    var speakers    map[uint32]*gopus.Decoder
    if c == nil {
        return
    }

    var err error
    for {
        p, ok := <-v.OpusRecv
        if !ok {
            return
        }

        if speakers == nil {
            speakers = make(map[uint32]*gopus.Decoder)
        }

        _, ok = speakers[p.SSRC]
        if !ok {
            speakers[p.SSRC], err = gopus.NewDecoder(16000, 1)
            if err != nil {
                OnError("error creating opus decoder", err)
                continue
            }
        }
        p.PCM, err = speakers[p.SSRC].Decode(p.Opus, 320, false)
        if err != nil {
            OnError("Error decoding opus data", err)
            continue
        }

        // try encoding pcm frame with Opus

        c <- p
    }
}

func Send(v *discordgo.VoiceConnection,  pcm <- chan []int16) {
    for {

        // read pcm from chan, exit if channel is closed.
        recv, ok := <-pcm
        if !ok {
            OnError("PCM Channel closed", nil)
            return
        }


        buf := make([]byte,2*len(recv))

        for i := 0; i < len(recv); i+=2 {
            var h, l uint8 = uint8(i>>8), uint8(i&0xff)
            buf[i] = h
            buf[i+1] = l
        }


        stream.Send(&speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest{
            StreamingRequest: &speechpb.StreamingRecognizeRequest_AudioContent{
                AudioContent: buf,
            },
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: Please provide code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

The Google Speech-to-Text documentation has [a fully working example of streaming speech recognition in Go](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-recognize-go).

*"Audio data is being streamed too slow"* is sent by the server when it is not receiving audio in realtime. In this case, the above code contains a bug that results in only half a PCM frame being sent on each iteration of the Send loop:

```
        for i := 0; i < len(recv); i+=2 {
            var h, l uint8 = uint8(i>>8), uint8(i&0xff)
            buf[i] = h
            buf[i+1] = l
        }
```

recv is a slice of int16 values, so it should be iterated over one value at a time, not `i+=2`, which skips every other value. `buf` is a uint8 slice, so the indexing for that is valid.

---